# udev rule not applied on boot for mounted disk

Tags: mount, centos7, udev

I'm trying to persist a readahead rule on a mounted drive to use with mongodb.

The mount is persisted using `/etc/fstab` and that works as expected.

I have added a udev rule `ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdb", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="16"`in `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-mongod.rules` and confirmed that it works with `udevadm test --action=add /sys/block/sdb`.

On reboot the disk is mounted but the readahead is set to the default value, not the value set by the udev rule.

I'm running `centOS 7.1` on google cloud and mounting a persistent disk.

Is this a race condition or another timing issue? Are there any workarounds? I'm reluctant to use `/etc/rc.local` since I'm not sure if the disk will always be mounted when it's executed, but not sure if  that is actually an issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am having the same issue - were you ever able to find a solution?

Comment: Nope, gave up. Just added `blockdev --setra 32 {{disk_device_path}}` to `rc.local` instead. So far it's working but I've only restarted the machines a couple of times so I'm not sure if it's consistent.

Comment: That's a bummer - `rc.local` works, but I like udev since the rule can apply based on wildcards and such

Comment: I think your rule is not picked up / too far behind. Try to use the uuid of the disk, see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/521402/use-uuid-in-udev-rules-and-mount-usb-drive-on-media-uuid

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Red Hat login: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4378581

```
cat /lib/tuned/throughput-performance/tuned.conf | grep -iB1 readahead
```

You will want to change "readahead=>4096" to "readahead=>0".